# Sending one Jquery AJAX request, but receiving multiple requests on PHP side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have researched dozens of answers but can't find the solution.

I have jQuery Ajax call on mouseover. 
I see one log in a browser console.
But PHP side receives 2 requests.

My JS code:

```
$('.df_word').off("mouseover").on("mouseover", function(){
    console.log("open translation_box"); //fires once on hover
    get_translation($(this),$(this).html());
}

function get_translation(word_el,word_html){
    console.log('get_translation'); //fires once on hover

    var params = {}
    params['api'] = "2.0";
    params['page'] = "translate";
    params['q'] = ""+word_html+"";

    console.log(params); //fires once on hover
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: window.api_link,
        data: params,
        error: function( xhr, textStatus ) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); //fires once on hover
        }
    });
}
```

On PHP side I see 2 requests within the same second (I save every request to the database).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are they both `GET` requests? The first might be an `OPTIONS` request, since this is cross-domain.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting just one log message in the browser's console? Sometimes they show up as one message with a number indicating how many times the same message was received.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký Yes, 100% sure. Only one.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, as I see. `Type: get` focused on that.

Comment: Do you see multiple requests in the `Network` tab of the browser?

Comment: Problem could also be on the server (in PHP). For example if you use some sort of redirect after the request is saved to the database, it could trigger another request, thus another row in the database.

Comment: @barmar I see 2 :( Initiator "other" and initiator "jquery.min.js:4". What does it mean?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I know. But there is now any redirects. I have only one INSERT INTO in test mode.

Comment: The one from `jquery.min.js` is the `$.ajax` call, I'm not sure what the other one is.

Comment: @barmar The first Ajax Call is an `OPTIONS` request. Could be this a problem? I have cross-domain request.

Comment: That's normal for cross-domain AJAX, it's part of the CORS protocol.